# ActionBar on android suddenly on every new activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've bee working on an app for a few months now. I'm trying to create a new activity which I have done many times before, but now when I try eclipse forces me to have an action bar. None of my other activities have this and would prefer not use one now. Any ideas on why this is happening and if there is a way to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a combination of the new-activity wizard templates and the new-project wizard. For an existing project, either do not use the new-activity wizard to add activities, or [add my "really blank activity" template and use it](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-rba).

Reportedly, there will be an "Empty activity" template showing up in a future version of the ADT plugin for Eclipse that will help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the onCreate method **BEFORE** calling setContentView()

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

or

check whether user has Honeycomb or higher

```
 //compare the version the user is running with the version the ActionBar was added
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
  ActionBar ab = Activity.getActionBar();
  ab.hide();}
```